How to detect grid lines and text in handwritten document?
I have many images of handwritten birth-death registry information from the 18th century which I want to process programmatically. The original texts are highly irregular, usually written left-to-right along a grid that may or may not be visible, often entered by different people, with notes scribbled over, etc. The images are always grayscale JPEG.
My aim is to find horizontal and vertical grid lines in the image to partition it to cells, after which I look for text blocks that roughly correspond to these cells (but may overlap multiple cell). So far, I struggle even to find the grid lines. This is where I am after cropping and splitting 2-page images:
i1 = Import["https://i.imgur.com/ymND27F.jpeg"]

(* Find text blocks *)
bd = TextRecognize[i1, "Word", "BoundingBox"];
i2 = Binarize[GaussianFilter[i1, 1, {0, 1}], 0.05];

(* Find text to be masked out for grid detection *)
mask = DeleteBorderComponents@DeleteSmallComponents[
    MorphologicalBinarize@Dilation[i2, DiskMatrix[15/2]], 500];
i3 = Binarize@ColorNegate@ImageAdjust[i1, {10, .2, 5}];
i4 = ImageCompose[i3, SetAlphaChannel[ImageAdjust[i3, {0, -1, 1}], 
    Dilation[mask, DiskMatrix@20]]];
lines = ImageLines[i4]; (* This is slow, may take a few seconds *)

{Show[i1, ImageSize -> 300],
 Show[{ColorNegate@i1, 
   Graphics[{EdgeForm@Directive[Yellow, Opacity@.5], FaceForm@None, 
     bd}]}, ImageSize -> 300],
 Show[ColorNegate@i1, Graphics[{Green, lines}], ImageSize -> 300]
 }


Some text blocks are missed, and most of the internal horizontal and vertical lines are not recognized. I am sure Mathematica is up to handling such tasks (even if not that fast), but I cannot seem to finetune the built-in functions to reliably detect objects. My questions therefore are:

How to improve TextRecognize to detect all blocks above a certain minimum size?
How to improve ImageLines to detect all vertical and horizontal lines?
What is a fast method to find correspondence beetween text blocks and grid cells?
How to speed up the whole process?
(((+1: Can I train a neural net to detect handwritten text based on what I have already deciphered manually? Yes, I understand that it is a huge topic and that there exist specialized software (e.g. Tesseract), but I am interested in a native Mathematica solution, if possible.)))


So-so: himg = DerivativeFilter[Binarize[i1, 0.75], {2, 0}, 38] // ImageAdjust // Binarize // ColorNegate // Thinning; lines = himg // ImageLines; Show[ColorNegate@i1,   Graphics[{Green, Select[lines, (# + 1/#) &@Abs[(*slope*)First@Ratios[First@Differences@First@#]] > 10 &]}],   ImageSize -> 300]: https://i.sstatic.net/bZGcwLAU.png. Not really my area.

Also so-so: wc = WatershedComponents[Binarize[i1, 0.75]] // Colorize; hlines = DerivativeFilter[wc, {2, 0}, 2] // Binarize[#, 0.025] & // DeleteSmallComponents // ImageLines // Select[Abs[Ratios@First@Differences@First@#][[1]] < 0.02 &]; vlines = DerivativeFilter[wc, {0, 2}, 2] // Binarize[#, 0.01] & // DeleteSmallComponents // ImageLines // Select[1/Abs[Ratios@First@Differences@First@#][[1]] < 0.05 &]; Show[i1, Graphics[{Orange, vlines, hlines}], ImageSize -> 300]: https://i.sstatic.net/LRn1bK9d.png
